# Chart.js : How to zoom bar on hover

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I created a chart with Chart.js and I would like each bar to have a zoom effect on hover, the same effect as a transform: scale in CSS.

Here is my current code :

```js
const thirdlabels = [
  'January',
  'February',
  'March',
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
];

const thirddata = {
  labels: thirdlabels,
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [30, 10, 20, 2, 20, 35],
  }]
};

const thirdconfig = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: thirddata,
  options: {}
};

const thirdChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart3'),
  thirdconfig
);
```

```css
#thirdChart {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Graphics</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div id="thirdChart">
            <canvas id="myChart3" aria-label="chart" role="img"></canvas>
        </div>
       
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried creating a plugin but I can't figure out where I can change the style.
Thanks.